# Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver'

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I always get this error: Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver'. Checking on the web I understood that isn't a specific error and probably my problem is in my Route but i can't see any problem...
Here my code:

```
window.Notes = Ember.Application.create();

Notes.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

Notes.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('notes', { path: '/' });
});

Notes.NotesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
    model: function (){             
        return this.store.find('note'); 
    }
});

Notes.NotesController = Ember.ObjectController.extend ();

Notes.Note = DS.Model.extend ({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string'),
});

Notes.Note.FIXTURES = [
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'hello world',
    body: 'ciao ciao ciao ciao',
    url: '...'
},
{   
    id: 2,
    title: 'javascript frameworks',
    body: 'Backbone.js, Ember.js, Knockout.js',
    url: '...'

},
{
    id: 3,
    title: 'Find a job in Berlin',
    body: 'Monster, beralinstartupjobs.com',
    url: '...'
}
]
```

Here the html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<div class="wrap">
  {{#each itemController="note"}}
    <section>
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <p>{{body}}</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="URL:" class="input" />
    </section>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

I already tried to change Notes.NotesController = Ember.ObjectController.extend (); with Notes.NotesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend ();

but I still get the error. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As he stated above, I was in the process of making a JSBin but I got pulled away.

Here ya go:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OhUXiRi/1/edit

The controller is automatically generated for you.

Comment: So, you're missing a closing script tag above Ember data.

Also, your application template has no controller or model being passed to it, you need an index route that returns a model for that {{each}}. 

Check this out: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uCaXeXU/3/edit

Comment: Also, you were using {{each}} in your noteController which was an objectController rather than an array controller. I had to change the template to 'note' rather than 'notes' and remove the {{each}}.

Comment: Download the Ember inspector extension for Chrome, it will really help you understand what is being generated and what Ember is looking for you to override. In general, it seems that you're missing the correlation between templates, routes, and controller naming. Each route has a parent template/route, and then child routes/templates.Application template is usually an {{outlet}}. Then your Notes route would be path: "/notes/" or "/" and you'd define "notes" template/route and "notes/index" template/route. Then add the dynamic nested route path: ":note_id".

Comment: Thank yoU! Now is all more clear!! That's my first app with Ember and with an MVC in general so I still try to understand how all the magic happen :) I didn't think that if I iterate over the model in the index template I don't have to do again in the other template. But now make sense.

Comment: Actually I have the Ember Chrome inspector, it help for the structure but not if you have an error, so I was a bit lost :)

Comment: Good stuff, you can always join us on IRC at #EmberJS on Freenode.net and ask away for a quicker response.

Comment: Also, can you please mark the question as answered if you're satisfied :D

Comment: Thanks, is work perfectly. So every different templates I have different routes, right?

Comment: For every route in Router you have a route, template and a controller. You will also have an index template, route, and controller for every parent route.

It all stems from the Router.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Notes.NotesController` need to be a subclass of `Ember.ArrayController`, because the returned data from `NotesRoute` `model` hook is an array like (DS.RecordArray).

After this you will receive an error because you are declaring a `itemController="note"` ember expects a controller called `Notes.NoteController` and it need to be a subclass of `Ember.ObjectController`. That controller will wrap each element in the `#each` view helper.

To summarise, this is missing in your code:

```
Notes.NotesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();

Notes.NoteController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();
```

Please, give a look in this fiddle with the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/Ly8K6/

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried out and I still get the error so i copy your code and.. works! Basically the problem wasn't the Controller (just ObjectController it works fine) but the templates. Now i specify an application template with {{outlet}} and my perosnal template="note" and now it work. But i didn't get it why...

Comment: When NotesRoute return an array from your model method, your respective controller, NotesController, have to subclass the ArrayController. But if you don't declare the NotesController, ember will automatically generated a correct controller for you. The `itemController` property in the {{#each}} servers to wrap each element of the iteration in a controller, because this it need to be a ObjectController subclass, because each element is an object. But the itemController isn't required, you just use it when you want to use additional properties without poluate your models.

Comment: Seem that i still not really get it what is the problem. Now I need to create a nested router and I get that error again. I try to play around with Controllers and templates name but I can't understand the right logic behind it :( http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uCaXeXU/1/